# ApplyPropertyChanges does not contains a definition using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I got this error when I trying to modify the Delete method in an MVC application.

> Error 1   'ContactManager.Models.ContactManagerDBEntities2' does not
>   contain a definition for 'ApplyPropertyChanges' and no extension
>   method 'ApplyPropertyChanges' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ContactManager.Models.ContactManagerDBEntities2' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   c:\users\sp_admin\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\ContactManager\ContactManager\Controllers\HomeController.cs 123 25  ContactManager
>
> Error 2   'ContactManager.Models.Contact' does not contain a definition
>   for 'EntityKey' and no extension method 'EntityKey' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ContactManager.Models.Contact' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   c:\users\sp_admin\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\ContactManager\ContactManager\Controllers\HomeController.cs 123 62  ContactManager

Here is the HomeControllers.cs

```
    // GET: /Home/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var contactToDelete = (from c in _entities.Contacts
                               where c.Id == id
                               select c).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(contactToDelete);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Home/Delete/5

    [HttpPost]
    /* public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)  */
    public ActionResult Delete(Contact contactToDelete)
    {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
          return View();
       try
       {
          var originalContact = (from c in _entities.Contacts
          where c.Id == contactToDelete.Id
          select c).FirstOrDefault();
          _entities.ApplyPropertyChanges(originalContact.EntityKey.EntitySetName, 
           contactToDelete);   <== here is the code in error ApplyPropertyChanges and
                                    EntityKey.
          _entities.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Here is the ContactManagerModel.Context.cs   I think something is missing in this ?? but this 
was generated from a template.

```
namespace ContactManager.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class ContactManagerDBEntities2 : DbContext
    {
        public ContactManagerDBEntities2()
            : base("name=ContactManagerDBEntities2")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Contact.cs

```
namespace ContactManager.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any idea what can be wrong since This code was generated from a template?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to call the `Remove` method to delete the instance of Contact. See below:

```
try
{
  _entities.Contacts.Remove(contactToDelete);
  _entities.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Update:
When you update a instance of `Contact`:

```
_entities.Contacts.Attach(updatedContact);
_entities.Entry(updatedContact).State = EntityState.Modified;
_entities.SaveChanges();
```

For more information, take a look at the following link, it's a good article about CRUD operations using Entity Framework.
[CRUD Operations Using Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640302/CRUD-Operations-Using-Entity-Framework-5-0-Code-Fi)

Comment: I got the same problem with the Edit, do you know what will be the proper term for Edit ?  _entities,Contacts. ????  I can't find what will be the same as Update.  Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the following link, it's good article about `CRUD` operations using `Entity Framework`. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640302/CRUD-Operations-Using-Entity-Framework-5-0-Code-Fi

Comment: works now for the edit but when I delete it goes the the delete.aspx for a confirmation but it is not removing the selected rows when I perform the go back to list the deleted id is still there, any idea ?  I performed the code you ansered

Comment: When you refresh the page, is the deleted row still there?  If it's still there, go check if you're using the `Seed`.